# javafx.scene.paint.Color#darker() not same as java.awt.Color#darker()

Tags: java, javafx, awt

I noticed that JavaFX darker color (`Color.BLUE.darker()`) is not the same as the awt version. I have resorted to using the underlying rgb codes to convert from one to another. Is there a better way to do this?

Also, does anyone know why the 2 color schemes are not compatible?

Comment: It's no particular surprise that they are not equivalent. These are two independent UI toolkits, written by two different programming teams. The interpretation of "darker" is inherently subjective, and indeed the [docs for `java.awt.Color.darker()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#darker--) state that an *arbitrary* scale is applied to the rgb values. If you need both toolkits, converting colors using the raw rgba values is an appropriate approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaFX: `javafx.scene.paint.Color#darker` creates new `javafx.scene.paint.Color` object based on parent color with adding hue, saturation, brightness and opacity (`private static final double DARKER_BRIGHTER_FACTOR = 0.7;`).

AWT: `java.awt.Color#darker()` works a little bit differently, it create new `java.awt.Color` based on RGB parent model with adding opacity value(`private static final double FACTOR = 0.7;`).

Answer on your question: they are not compatible.

Comment: Its a shame that Sun/Oracle didnt maintain consistency across the 2 frameworks. A minor annoyance when migrating systems.